# Cannot get specific WMS to display in Leaflet or OpenLayers 3

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, wms

I am trying to create a map in both Leaflet and OpenLayers 3 which displays the  layer `EMAP8` from the WMS `http://wms.nlsc.gov.tw/wms`. I can't get it to work. I can open the layer in QGIS, but when I try to use it in Leaflet like this:

```
var overlay_taiwanemapen0 = L.tileLayer.wms('http://wms.nlsc.gov.tw/wms', {
    layers: 'EMAP8',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    continuousWorld : true,
});
```

or in OpenLayers 3 like this:

```
var lyr_taiwanemapen = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
        url: "http://wms.nlsc.gov.tw/wms",
        params: {"LAYERS": "EMAP8", "TILED": "true"},
    })),
    title: "taiwane-map(en)",
});
```

I get nothing displayed. I can see layers being requested, and data being transferred, but nothing on the map.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### OpenLayers 3

The `VERSION` in WMS request parameter `params` in [OL3](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html), when omitted, is 1.3.0.

You simple have to add the parameter `'VERSION': '1.1.1'` to your request. You can check the version supported by the server from the capabilities document.

Solution for OpenLayers 3:

```
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
        url: "http://wms.nlsc.gov.tw/wms",
        params: {"LAYERS": "EMAP8", "TILED": true, 'VERSION': '1.1.1' },
    })),
    title: "taiwane-map(en)",
})
```

I've setup a [fiddle using your WMS](http://jsfiddle.net/jgrocha/mdy7962j/).

The full code is:

```
var layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
      url: "http://wms.nlsc.gov.tw/wms",
      params: {
        "LAYERS": "EMAP8",
        "TILED": true,
        'VERSION': '1.1.1'
      },
    })),
    title: "taiwane-map(en)",
  })
];
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers, // [lyr_taiwanemapen],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [120, 23],
    zoom: 6
  })
});
```

#### Leaflet (versions prior than 1.x)

The code provided in the question runs without any problem in Leaflet, in versions prior to 1.x.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([23, 120], 5);

var overlay_taiwanemapen0 = L.tileLayer.wms('http://wms.nlsc.gov.tw/wms', {
    layers: 'EMAP8',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    continuousWorld : true,
});

overlay_taiwanemapen0.addTo(map);
```

This working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgrocha/p126259k/) has the code provided in the question.

#### Leaflet 1.x

In Leaflet 1.x all WMS query parameters are in lowercase, which is fine for servers following the [WMS specification](http://cite.opengeospatial.org/OGCTestData/wms/1.1.1/spec/wms1.1.1.html#basic_elements.param_rules.order_and_case).

To provide compatibility with non compliant servers requiring WMS query parameters in uppercase, there is an optional parameter `uppercase: true`.

The solution with Leaflet 1.x is:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([23, 120], 5);
var overlay_taiwanemapen0 = L.tileLayer.wms('http://wms.nlsc.gov.tw/wms', {
    layers: 'EMAP8',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    continuousWorld : true,
    uppercase: true
});
overlay_taiwanemapen0.addTo(map);
```

Check this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgrocha/q66z7c2h/) with the code for Leaflet 1.x.

Comment: Confirmed in OL3, which was defaulting to WMS v1.3.0. Thank you. However, Leaflet's default WMS version is 1.1.1 (confirmed that the individual tile requests are stipulating 1.1.1 in browser dev tools network tab). Anyone know the Leaflet answer?

Comment: It works on Leaflet. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgrocha/p126259k/).

Comment: Just an additional note: this specific WMS server expects WMS parameters in uppercase. To get it work with Leaflet versions 1.x, it is necessary to add the open `uppercase: true` to the layer specification.

Comment: The Web Map Service specification (version 1.1.1) tells us that:  _Thus, the SERVICE parameter of the request **shall** have the value "WMS"_  So the service here is just following the specification

Comment: @nmtoken You are right. The value of the SERVICE query parameter is WMS. I've just pointed out that this specific service requires all parameters (like SERVICE, REQUEST, VERSION, LAYERS, etc) in uppercase, like this: `http://wms.nlsc.gov.tw/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=EMAP8&STYLES=&FORMAT=(...)`
**Parameter names shall not be case sensitive, but parameter values shall be case sensitive**, as stated in [Web Map Service Implementation Specification](http://cite.opengeospatial.org/OGCTestData/wms/1.1.1/spec/wms1.1.1.html#basic_elements.param_rules.order_and_case)

Comment: Can you add the `uppercase` to your answer?